# Adding Discount code button to Paypal buy now button

Tags: javascript, html, paypal, discount, paypal-buttons

I'm trying to add a discount code to the paypal button, The javascript works and says the discount code is valid but isn't taking the discount off the amount when you click the buy now button to pay.

Can anyone help me please

```
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
<p>Please click on the link to pay</p>
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_cart" />
<input type="hidden" name="upload" value="1" />
<input type="hidden" name="business" value="<?php echo C_OUR_EMAIL; ?>" />
<input type="hidden" name="first_name" value="<?php echo strfordisp($ofirstname); ?>" />
<input type="hidden" name="last_name" value="<?php echo strfordisp($olastname); ?>" />
<input type="hidden" name="address1" value="<?php echo strfordisp($theorder["oaddress"]); ?>" />
<input type="hidden" name="address2" value="<?php echo strfordisp($theorder["oaddress2"]); ?>" />
<input type="hidden" name="address3" value="<?php echo strfordisp($theorder["oaddress3"]); ?>" />
<input type="hidden" name="city" value="<?php echo strfordisp($theorder["otown"]); ?>">
<input type="hidden" name="zip" value="<?php echo strfordisp($theorder["opostcode"]); ?>" />


<?php
$orderdets = mysql_query("select * from c4d_orderitems where orderid='" . $_SESSION["db_order"] . "' and confirm");
$iloop = 1;
while ($orderrow = mysql_fetch_array($orderdets))
{
$itemdesc = $orderrow["itemtypedesc"];
$itemdesc .= " to " . $orderrow["dpostcode"];
$itemprice = $orderrow["cost"] + $orderrow["surcharge"] + $orderrow["insurancecost"];
?>
<input type='hidden' name="item_name_<?php echo $iloop; ?>" value='<?php echo strfordisp($itemdesc); ?>' />
<input type='hidden' name="item_number_<?php echo $iloop; ?>" value='<?php echo $orderrow["itemtype"]; ?>' />
<input type='hidden' name="amount_<?php echo $iloop; ?>" value='<?php
  if ((strtoupper($ofirstname)=="PCTRENDSTEST") || (strtoupper($olastname)=="PCTRENDSTEST") || (substr($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'],0,11)=="82.152.55.1"))
  echo("0.01");
  else echo $itemprice;
?>' />


<input type='hidden' name="baseamt_<?php echo $iloop; ?>" value='<?php if ((strtoupper($ofirstname)=="PCTRENDSTEST") || (strtoupper($olastname)=="PCTRENDSTEST") || (substr($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'],0,11)=="82.152.55.1"))
  echo("0.01");
  else echo $itemprice;
?>' />
 <input type="hidden" name="basedes_<?php echo $iloop; ?>" value="" />



<input type='hidden' name="quantity_<?php echo $iloop; ?>" value='1' />

<?
    $iloop++;
  }
  ?>
<input type="hidden" name="return" value="<?php echo C_SITE_ROOT; ?>stage7.php" />
<meta http-equiv="return" content="3;url=stage7.php" />
<input type="hidden" name="cancel-return" value="<?php echo C_SITE_ROOT; ?>order-cancel.php" />
<input type="hidden" name="notify_url" value="<?php echo C_SITE_ROOT; ?>paypal.php" />
<input type="hidden" name="rm" value="2" />
<input type="hidden" name="invoice" value="<?php echo $_SESSION["db_order"]; ?>" />
<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="GBP" />
<input type="hidden" name="no-shipping" value="1" />
<input type="hidden" name="button_subtype" value="products" />
<input type="hidden" name="bn" value="PP-BuyNowBF:btn_buynowCC_LG.gif:NonHostedGuest" />
<input type="hidden" name="country" value="GB" />


Enter Coupon code
<input type="text" size="10" name="coupcode"; />
<input type="button" value="Check code" onclick="coupval =this.form.coupcode.value;  ChkCoup();" />



<p class='fmenu'><input type="image" src="https://www.paypal.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_buynowCC_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!">
     <img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypal.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1"></p>
     </form>
```

The javascript is:

```
var discnt = 0;   // no default percent discount



var coupons = new Array (  // place to put coupon codes

  "coup1",                 // 1st coupon value - comma seperated

  "coup2",                 // 2nd coupon value - add all you want

  "coup3"                  // 3rd coupon value
);
var coupdc  = new Array ( 5,10,15
 // place to put discounts for coupon vals
);
var coupval = "(blanket)"; // what user entered as coupon code
function ChkCoup () {      // check user coupon entry
var i;
  discnt = 0;              // assume the worst
  for (i=0; i<coupons.length; i++) {
    if (coupval == coupons[i]) {
      discnt = coupdc[i];  // remember the discount amt
      alert ("This is a valid promo code! \n\n" + discnt + "%" +" discount now in effect.");
      return;

    }
  }
  alert ("'" + coupval + "'  is not a valid promo code!");
}
function Pound (val) {      // force to valid Pound amount
var str,pos,rnd=0;
  if (val < .995) rnd = 1;  // for old Netscape browsers
  str = escape (val*1.0 + 0.005001 + rnd);  // float, round, escape
  pos = str.indexOf (".");
  if (pos > 0) str = str.substring (rnd, pos + 3);
  return str;
}
function ReadForm (obj1) {  // apply the discount
var amt,des;
  amt = obj1.amount_<?php echo $iloop; ?>.value*1.0;       // base amount
  des = obj1.basedes_<?php echo $iloop; ?>.value;           // base description
  if (discnt > 0) {                   // only if discount is active
    amt = Pound (amt - (amt * discnt/100.0));
    des = des + ", " + discnt + "%" + "dis, COUP = " + coupval;
  }
  obj1.amount.value = Pound (amt);
  obj1.item_name.value = des; 
}
```

Comment: I don't see the code for deducting discount from the price. Are you doing that somewhere else?

Comment: sorry i have miss that function off when copying the code over

Comment: Where are you calling `ReadForm` from?

Comment: Its not been called from anywhere

Comment: Okay, so you have logic for deducting discount from price in `ReadForm` which never gets called and hence, is not accessed. Try to call it on a button click or better yet, right after discount code is detected to be correct.

Comment: Okay the discount work does work though it just won't take it off in this buy now button for some reason

Comment: I used this tutorial to help me, but my paypal butotn is different http://icode4you.net/how-to-create-a-coupon-discount-for-paypal-buttons/